# How do I install a package when a vagrant box is created

Tags: vagrant

How do I install a package when a vagrant box is created.  Right now I'm using a shell provisioner to accomplish this, but this runs everytime I do a vagrant provision.  I would like the package to be installed only when the box boots.

I know I can repackage the box with the package already installed, but is there a concept of a bootstrap script that only runs once?

~Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Usually people will use an automation/deployment manager for this. The popular ones that comes to mind are :

Puppet: http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet

Chef: http://www.getchef.com/chef/

Answer (score 0):

make your bootstrap script run-once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -f ~/.runoncescriptname ]; then
  # install package here
  apt-get install ... && touch ~/.runoncescriptname
  #
fi
```